Should I specify the `engine` field in packages.json for a browser library project?
For a JS library project that is intended to be used in browser, should I specify the engines field in packages.json?

You don't have to define engines if package is only supposed to work in the browser.
You can specify browser key https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#browser
